# How can I extract a chunk of text within a table?

Tags: python

new to Python here and I would like to know how to extract a chunk of text within a html table using Python.

Here is the url link: "http://www.cityu.edu.hk/sds/web/studentlife_scholarships_awards.shtml"

As you can see, there are a number of application deadlines and I would like to extract all the dates (e.g. "5 p.m., 15 November 2021 (Monday)") from the table, can anyone show me how to do it using beautiful soup?

What I tried:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.cityu.edu.hk/sds/web/studentlife_scholarships_awards.shtml"
source = requests.get(url)

import bs4 as bs 
page_html = bs.BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')

External_Awards = page_html.find_all('table', class_= 'marginBottom10')
print(External_Awards)

application_deadline = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    appdead = row.select('br:nth-of-type(1)')[0].text
    print("application_deadline")
    print(appdead)
    application_deadline.append(appdead)
```

Answer (score 2):

`pandas` can read `html` tables directly, using `BeautifulSoup` under the hood.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('http://www.cityu.edu.hk/sds/web/studentlife_scholarships_awards.shtml')[0].rename(columns={1:'text'}) #read the table; pandas returns a list of tables on a webpage, we need the first item, [0], and rename the second column to 'text'
df['date'] = df['text'].str.split('Application deadline: ').str[1] #split the text and get the first item of the list
df = df[['text', 'date']] #keep only the text and date columns
```

You'll now have a dataframe `print(df.head())`:

|  | text | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Croucher Scholarships for Doctoral Studies 2022 Croucher Fellowships for Postdoctoral Research 2022 Croucher Research Studentships 2022 Croucher Science Communication Studentships 2022 Application deadline: 5 p.m., 15 November 2021 (Monday) | 5 p.m., 15 November 2021 (Monday) |
| 1 | Personal Finance Ambassador Programme 2021/22 個人理財大使計劃 2021/22 Application deadline: 12:00 noon, 10 October 2021 (Sunday) | 12:00 noon, 10 October 2021 (Sunday) |
| 2 | Li Kwan Hung Education Fund 2021/22 Application deadline: 15 October 2021 (Friday) | 15 October 2021 (Friday) |
| 3 | Friends of the Earth (HK) CESGA® Scholarship Program 2021 Application deadline: 22 October 2021 (Friday) | 22 October 2021 (Friday) |
| 4 | Toi Shan Association of Hong Kong Ltd. Scholarship/ Bursary 2021 香港台山商會有限公司獎學金／助學金 2021 Application deadline: 7 October 2021 (Thursday) | 7 October 2021 (Thursday) |

You can export to csv (and many other formats): `df.to_csv('output.csv')`